# Error in accessing my PHPMyAdmin instance

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was working on my website application. PHPMyAdmin is working just fine until I restarted my computer. When I tried accessing PHPMyAdmin, I got this error:

[image]

I didn't do anything weird before that. I just worked with my codes. I don't know what to do. My codes still work in the browser and it seems like the data are still there. But I can't access PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Clear your cookies and try again.

Comment: why dont you just copy and past the default php.ini file

Comment: ccleaner is a good software try this to clear cookie

Comment: @Mayankswami, do you mean pasting the code on my php.ini here?

Comment: @Mayankswami, where can I get ccleaner? Is that a software?

Comment: http://www.filehippo.com/download_ccleaner/

Comment: @Mayankswami, I have my php.ini inside C:\xampp\php\ already.

Comment: @Mayankswami, is there any other way to clean the cookies without installing a software. I'm not allowed to install software in my computer. Thanks

Comment: ya which browser are you using

Comment: for all http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=32050  for only google chrome http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95582 for firefox i think its best http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-cookies-remove-info-websites-stored

Comment: and i would also like to suggest use firefox with firebug,webdeveloper tools and pagespeed there are such a great tools for webdeveloper

Comment: @Mayankswami, post your comment as answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot! :)))

Comment: I was facing similar issue. It showed error while using localhost/phpmyadmin but it worked with 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin. Clearing cache worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solve by clear the cookie . To know how to clear cookie check this 
[Clearing cache and cookies](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=32050) link . you can also use the [Web Developer tools for google chrome](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) and for firefox [webdeveloper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) to see and clear cookie